# How to monitor rstudio-server.status using shellscript

Tags: bash, service, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor the rstudio-server.status using a bash script and cron it to run every 5minutes and push the status of the service to a logfile. But, somehow i'm unable to get the status of the service.

```
service=rstudio-server.service
if [[ $(systemctl status $service)]] ; then
echo "$service is running !! nothing to worry!"
else
  /usr/lib/$service start
fi
```

is this a goodway to monitor?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Add a space here: `if [[ $(systemctl status $service) ]]`

Comment: Thank  you, so much. But how do i track if it's running or not??, and how do i make it to restart if it is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it a long back ago, posting it now. 
Thank you all!

```
#!/bin/bash
# Shell-guy to monitor a process (0~0)
#<script.sh> "service_name"

service=$1
if [ "$(systemctl status $service | grep -c "active (running)")" -gt 0 ];then
   echo "$service is running !!"
elif [ "$(systemctl status $service | grep -c "active (running)")" -eq 0 ];then
   echo "$service is not running"
   $service restart
   if [ "$(systemctl status $service | grep -c "active (running)")" -lt 1 ];then
     $service restart
   elif [ "$(systemctl status $service | grep -c "active (running)")" -eq 0 ];then
     echo "The service is not found!!"
   fi
fi
```